# Recipe failing to remove /usr/sbin/useradd

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

So, I have a custom yocto layer in which I need to remove the user account modification commands (useradd, userdel, usermod, etc.). These commands are stored within /usr/sbin. The method I've been attempting is to introduce a new recipe (or add the same logic in an existing recipe) where I do as such:

```
SUMMARY = "User account modification controls"
DESCRIPTION = "Configures the existence of user modification commands"
LICENSE = "Proprietary"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/Proprietary;md5=[redacted]"


#SRC_URI += ""

FILES_${PN} += " \
    ${sbindir}/* \
"


do_install() {
    rm -rf ${D}${sbindir}/useradd
}
```

The important part of course being in the do_install, where useradd should be getting removed from /usr/sbin. Although this doesn't happen. I've verified the recipe is getting parsed properly, and I've attempted to add the same logic into my primary image recipe. Bitbake completes successfully, although rootfs, and a boot both show that /usr/sbin/useradd still exist. Maybe there's something I'm misunderstanding about how useradd is being generated.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add bbappend for the package that ships `useradd` and delete it there.

Comment: That was my initial strategy, although there is no recipe that ships useradd. There are however recipes that utilize it within oe-core. I believe useradd and the other related commands are added in some different way that I'm not aware of, and can't seem to find much information on.